# c++ template specialization for container of reference_wrapper

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, template-specialization

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <algorithm>

class MyClass {
};

template <typename C, typename V, typename Enable = void>
static bool Contains(const C& container, const V& value) {
    auto iter = std::find(container.begin(), container.end(), value);
    auto result = (iter != container.end());
    return result;
}

template <typename C, typename V,
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<std::reference_wrapper<const V>, typename C::value_type>::value, bool>::type>
static bool Contains(const C& container, const V& value) {
    auto iter = std::find_if(container.begin(), container.end(), [&](auto& aValue) {
        return (aValue.get() == value);
    });
    auto result = (iter != container.end());
    return result;
}

int main() {
    const MyClass a;
    auto container = {
        std::reference_wrapper<const MyClass>(a),
    };
    Contains(container, a);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler: VC++2015U3

Compile error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error C2678   binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand
>   operand of type 'const std::reference_wrapper' (or
>   there is no acceptable conversion)    ConsoleApplication1 c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility  3258

It runs into the first implementation rather than the second one.

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need also an `operator==()` for `MyClass` but, to solve the specialization problem, I think is better to use an explicit specialization

```
template <template <typename...> class C, typename V>
static bool Contains (C<std::reference_wrapper<V const>> const & container,
                      V const & value) {
    auto iter = std::find_if(container.begin(), container.end(), [&](auto& aValue) {
        return (aValue.get() == value);
    });
    auto result = (iter != container.end());
    return result;
}
```

instead of SFINAE.

Because if you also make SFINAE works to enable the reference-wrapper-container version, by example

```
template <typename C, typename V> 
static std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::reference_wrapper<const V>, 
                        typename C::value_type>::value, bool>
   Contains (const C& container, const V& value)
```

both versions of `Contains()` function matches the call

```
 Contains(container, a);
```

and no one is preferred.

Comment: I can only define a global operator==, the class method operator== doesn't work.

Comment: @user1633272 - usually the `operator==()` is defined not method, maybe `friend` to the class, function; you can also define it inside the class: `class MyClass { friend bool operator== (MyClass const &, MyClass const &) { return true; } };`

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `operator ==` to compare class instances:

```
bool operator ==(MyClass const & left, MyClass const & right) { return false; }
```

This operator will be invoked by `std::find` and `std::find_if` algorithms (rather inside of lambda `return (aValue.get() == value);` in the second case).